# ':selected' is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i was trying to make a button onclick check so that lists' option classes weren't same:

```
<select name="names1" id="names1">
   <option value="1" class="1">option 1</option>
   <option value="2" class="1">option 2</option>
   <option value="3" class="2">option 3</option>
</select>
<select name="names2" id="names2">
   <option value="1" class="1">option 1</option>
   <option value="2" class="1">option 2</option>
   <option value="3" class="2">option 3</option>
</select>
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="check"></button>


function check() {
  let optionClass1 = document.querySelector('select[name="names1"]').querySelector(':checked').attr('class')
  let optionClass2 = document.querySelector('select[name="names2"]').querySelector(':checked').attr('class')
  if (optionClass1 != optionClass2) {
    alert("e")
  }
}
```

but it's not workin: "':selected' is not a valid selector"

i dont know jack about jquery, please help

Comment: You're mixing base JS and jQuery; `document.querySelector('select[name="names1"]').querySelector(':checked')` is base JS, where jQuery would be `$('select[name="names1"]').find(':checked')`. Also, you're not using `:selected` anywhere in the code you posted... Did you mean `:checked` is not a valid selector?

Comment: You're mixing JS with jQuery. BTW, that is your intention when using `.attr('class')`?

Comment: is this a multiselect you are trying to check, else you would need to verify `value` of the select

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It looks like they're trying to use `.attr('class')` to see if the selected option of `names1` has the same **class** as the selected option of `names2`. So something like `$('#names1').find('option:selected').attr('class') == $('#names2').find('option:selected').attr('class')` as a one-liner.

Comment: Don't use `class` to store arbitrary data. Use the `data-*` attribute instead: `data-class="1"` , `data-class="2"` and get the value in JS using `myElement.dataset.class` - Also don't use numeric classNames anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) is *pure* JavaScript and it doesn't have any `.attr()` chainable Method.
[`.attr()` is a jQuery Method](https://api.jquery.com/attr/), therefore, instead of getting DOM elements using vanilla JS, use the `$()` jQuery Object constructor.

Don't use inline JavaScript `on*` handlers like `onclick`. Use [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead. JS (same as styles) should be in one place only and that's the respective tag or file.

Don't use `class=""` to store arbitrary **data**. Use the [valid HTML5 `data-*` attribute instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes):

Example using JavaScript (no libraries)

```js
function check() {
  const c1 = document.querySelector('select[name="names1"] option:checked').dataset.class;
  const c2 = document.querySelector('select[name="names2"] option:checked').dataset.class;

  if (c1 !== c2) {
    alert("e")
  }
}

document.querySelector("#check").addEventListener("click", check);
```

```html
<select name="names1" id="names1">
   <option value="1" data-class="1">option 1</option>
   <option value="2" data-class="1">option 2</option>
   <option value="3" data-class="2">option 3</option>
</select>
<select name="names2" id="names2">
   <option value="1" data-class="1">option 1</option>
   <option value="2" data-class="1">option 2</option>
   <option value="3" data-class="2">option 3</option>
</select>
<button type="button" name="button" id="check">CHECK</button>
```

or by using jQuery

```js
function check() {
  const c1 = $('select[name="names1"] option:checked').data("class");
  const c2 = $('select[name="names2"] option:checked').data("class");

  if (c1 !== c2) {
    alert("e")
  }
}

$("#check").on("click", check);
```

```html
<select name="names1" id="names1">
   <option value="1" data-class="1">option 1</option>
   <option value="2" data-class="1">option 2</option>
   <option value="3" data-class="2">option 3</option>
</select>
<select name="names2" id="names2">
   <option value="1" data-class="1">option 1</option>
   <option value="2" data-class="1">option 2</option>
   <option value="3" data-class="2">option 3</option>
</select>
<button type="button" name="button" id="check">CHECK</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```